# Disable telemetry spam on Modern UI pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, spfx, modern-experience, debugging

If you open a modern page, then press F12 and open the network tab you can observe a lot of telemetry-related activities every several seconds. It makes it harder to debug SPFx customizations.

Is there a way to somehow disable these spammy telemetry calls? At least for a short period of time?

[image]

I was told that we can add `?disableTelemetry=true` at the end of the URL to disable these telemetry calls, but it does not seem to work. Telemetry still goes through as usual.

I found the way to use Google Chrome network filters to partially remove telemetry, but I wonder if there a better option:

> In Chrome F12 Dev tools, on the Network tab there is a filter text
>   box. You can use it to write complex filter queries. This is how we
>   can filter out some telemetry requests:
>   -domain:browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com -domain:browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com

[image]

Comment: interesting post, I assume this is in SharePoint Online, which in that case.. do you really think MS would want to to turn off any of this... :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Test in different browsers and see if there's any difference.
2. If it's possible, switch to a different network.
3. Create a new Site Collection based on the team site template. Check if it runs into the same issue.
4. Add more Server Resource Quota to a SharePoint site collection.

This May Help,
Peter

Comment: Hi Peter. Thank you for your suggestion. Telemetry API calls will be sent regardless of which network or browser we are on. Telemetry is sent by design so it's not an "issue".